# How to remove a element from array cart in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, cart

I have this array

```
[
   0: {title: "Apple", price: 0.50, count: 1},
   1: {title: "Pizza", price: 5.50, count: 1},
   2: {title: "Hamburger", price: 4.50, count: 1},
   3: {title: "Coca Cola", price: 0.99, count: 1},
]
```

that I print with:

```
var dataAppunti = "";
    for (i = 0; i < appuntiFilter.length; i++){
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000)+1;
        dataAppunti += "<div id='"+rand+"' class='row pb-3 mx-3 mt-3' style='border-bottom:1px solid #eeeeee;'>";
        dataAppunti += "<div id='fs-7' class='col-2 text-center font-weight-bold quant'>";
        dataAppunti += appuntiFilter[i].count+"x";
        dataAppunti += "</div>";
        dataAppunti += "<div id='fs-7' class='col-5'>";
        dataAppunti += appuntiFilter[i].title+" "+i;
        dataAppunti += "</div>";
        dataAppunti += "<div class='col-3 pricep font-weight-bold text-right' style='color:#27c727;' id='price-app'>";
        dataAppunti += parseFloat(appuntiFilter[i].price).toFixed(2).toLocaleString()+" €";
        dataAppunti += "</div>";
        dataAppunti += "<div onclick='deleteItem("+i+")' class='col-2'><img src='delete.png' style='max-height:20px;' class='img-fluid' /></div>";
        dataAppunti += "</div>";
    }

    $("#list-appunti").html(dataAppunti);
```

In deleteitem:

```
function deleteItem(item){
   appuntiFilter.splice(item,1);
}
```

But if I remove for example the first item, the last item will no longer have code 3 but 2. How I can "scale" and refresh number of position whenever I delete an element?

Now I'm in this situation:

1x Apple 0.50€ delete (position 0)
1x Pizza 5.50€ delete (position 1)
1x Hamburger 4.50€ delete (position 2)
1x Coca Cola 0.50€ delete (position 3)

If I remove Apple will remain:

1x Pizza 5.50€ delete (position 1)
1x Hamburger 4.50€ delete (position 2)
1x Coca Cola 0.50€ delete (position 3)

Comment: Count of objects in array will always start from Zero. you can't change it 
try adding instead another key:value to your objects indicating a position.

Comment: Add this loop to a function named rerenderList or something like that, and run this function after every deletion.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the data at that index to undefined like following...

```
function deleteItem(item){
   appuntiFilter[appuntiFilter.indexOf(item)]=undefined ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need an order based on position on the Array I'd do something like the following.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('#list');
const containerChanged = document.querySelector('#list2');

const appuntiFilter = [{
    title: "Apple",
    price: 0.50,
    count: 1
  },
  {
    title: "Pizza",
    price: 5.50,
    count: 1
  },
  {
    title: "Hamburger",
    price: 4.50,
    count: 1
  },
  {
    title: "Coca Cola",
    price: 0.99,
    count: 1
  },
];

// Display list
appuntiFilter.forEach((el, idx) => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.textContent = `${el.title}, ${idx}`;
  container.appendChild(div);
})

// Delete first item.
appuntiFilter.splice(0,1);

// Show updated list.
appuntiFilter.forEach((el, idx) => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.textContent = `${el.title}, ${idx}`;
  containerChanged.appendChild(div);
})
```

```html
<div id="list">

</div>
<hr/>
<div id="list2">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can re-create the list after every deletion. It's an expensive operation but you can use it until you are not having thousands of items in the cart.
Plus, you wouldn't need to use jQuery to append the HTML. You can use DOMParser.
I don't exactly know how you are supplying the index of the list item you want to delete, so I have simply taken the first index. You can edit the `index = null` line to the index you want to delete.
I hope this helps.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="delete_item">Delete</button>
    <ul id="list-appunti"></ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    function renderList(appuntiFilter) {

        const list_appunti = document.getElementById('list-appunti');
        list_appunti.innerHTML = '';
        
        for (i = 0; i < appuntiFilter.length; i++){
            
            var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000)+1;

            const list_dom_string = `
                <div id="${rand}" class='row pb-3 mx-3 mt-3' style='border-bottom:1px solid #eeeeee;'>
                    <div id='fs-7' class='col-2 text-center font-weight-bold quant'>
                        ${appuntiFilter[i].count}x
                    </div>
                    <div class='col-3 pricep font-weight-bold text-right' style='color:#27c727;' id='price-app'>
                        ${parseFloat(appuntiFilter[i].price).toFixed(2).toLocaleString()}€
                    </div>
                    <div onclick='deleteItem("+i+")' class='col-2'><img src='delete.png' style='max-height:20px;' class='img-fluid' />
                    </div>
                </div>

            `;

            const parser = new DOMParser();
            const dom = parser.parseFromString(list_dom_string, 'text/html');

            list_appunti.appendChild(dom.body.children[0]);
            
        }

    }

    function deleteItem(list_appunti, index){

        list_appunti.splice(index ? index : 0, 1);

    }

    window.onload = function () {
        
        const appuntiFilter = [
           {title: "Apple", price: 0.50, count: 1},
           {title: "Pizza", price: 5.50, count: 1},
           {title: "Hamburger", price: 4.50, count: 1},
           {title: "Coca Cola", price: 0.99, count: 1},
        ];

        renderList(appuntiFilter);

        const delete_button = document.getElementById('delete_item');

        delete_button.addEventListener('click', function (e) {

            const index = null; // supply index?

            deleteItem(appuntiFilter, index);
            renderList(appuntiFilter);

        }, true);
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```